# Retrieve users/groups eligible for AzureAD PIM roles using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve using Microsoft Graph API the list of users/groups with **PIM eligible assignments** to Azure AD roles.

I would like to make the API calls from Python or from [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), not from the PowerShell script Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilitySchedule provided by Microsoft.

My script is able to connect with Microsoft Graph API, has the necessary API permissions, and can retrieve the complete list of AzureAD users and groups.

The issue is that I don't know how to map the output of API calls to `roleEligibilitySchedules` or `roleEligibilityScheduleInstances` to users or groups.

Example of output from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleEligibilitySchedules

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#roleManagement/directory/roleEligibilitySchedules",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "0c9c21ed-9569-42a4-9d72-810ad8063985",
            "principalId": "ef7b01fd-3d84-4338-a8c4-1aa6bb8c6021",
            "roleDefinitionId": "f28a1f50-f6e7-4571-818b-6a12f2af6b6c",
            "directoryScopeId": "/",
            "appScopeId": null,
            "createdUsing": "0c9c21ed-9569-42a4-9d72-810ad8063985",
            "createdDateTime": "2023-04-21T19:50:09.013Z",
            "modifiedDateTime": "0001-01-01T08:00:00Z",
            "status": "Provisioned",
            "memberType": "Direct",
            "scheduleInfo": {
                "startDateTime": "2023-04-21T19:50:09.013Z",
                "recurrence": null,
                "expiration": {
                    "type": "afterDateTime",
                    "endDateTime": "2024-04-20T19:49:44.26Z",
                    "duration": null
                }
            }
        },
[...]
```

Example of output from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#roleManagement/directory/roleEligibilityScheduleInstances

```
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#roleManagement/directory/roleEligibilityScheduleInstances",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "kl2Jm9Msx0SdAqasLV6lw8xwLnAVMmVCog68uCf1hnk-1-e",
            "principalId": "702e70cc-3215-4265-a20e-bcb827f58679",
            "roleDefinitionId": "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3",
            "directoryScopeId": "/",
            "appScopeId": null,
            "startDateTime": "2023-03-31T19:17:37.163Z",
            "endDateTime": null,
            "memberType": "Direct",
            "roleEligibilityScheduleId": "ee8673e5-f1b6-42f7-956e-1c297d82f480"
        },
[...]
```

What are the next steps to map the values retrieved above to user or group names, like in the Portal image?

[PIM Eligible users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qG7Z.png)

Thank you

Comment: Can you check this:Assign eligibility for a group (preview) in Privileged Identity Management:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/groups-assign-member-owner

Answer (score 0):

In the odata you receive, the
"principalId": "ef7b01fd-3d84-4338-a8c4-1aa6bb8c6021"
refers to the Entity that is elgible to activate this role assignment.

Hope that helps